# SQL Server Management Studio connection issue

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise on Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. The server runs SQL Server 2008 is machine M1. I have tried using SQL Server Management Studio on machine M2 could be connected to M1. But I can not use another machine M3 to connect to M1. Any ideas what is wrong? I am not sure whether it is the issue at M1 side or M3 side? Any check list?

Error message is, provider: named pipeline provider program, error 40 -- can not open connection to SQL Server (Microsoft SQL Server: error 53).

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On M1 you need to enable TCP/IP in SQL Server Configuration Manager, under "Protocols for MSSQLSERVER". In addition to this you need to open at least port 1433 in the Windows Firewall

Comment: If they are not enabled, how could M2 be able to connect to M1?

Comment: Could you describe more about your network, the difference between M2 and M3

Comment: 1. M2 and M1 are in server room, and M3 are outside server room. I think there should be some restrictions between connection from server room and non-server room. Could it be the root cause? 2. Besides enable TCP/IP, open firewall 1433 at M1, do you think anything else setting on M1 which may impact?

Comment: I think that's it. Check this article out: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

If this doesn't solve your issues, you should look at the connection between your server room and non-server room.
Btw, you can force a TCP connection with "tcp:" at the start of your server